# Problems compiling NDK project with Android Studio 1.3 preview

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, stl, android-ndk

Decided to give the new NDK support in Android studio a shot but seem to be running into an issue:

**Error: 'std::function' has not been declared**

Had a few other linking issues with stl libraries before but those were fixed by adding

**stl "stlport_static"
cFlags "-O2 --std=c++11 "**

to the Gradle config.

Has anyone dealt with anything similar? I've been googling this the past couple of days but most answers seem out of date or not related to Android Studio 1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact, not much has changed since around january 2014 regarding NDK support in Android Studio. The 1.3 version that is out right now is only preview 3, and the amazing NDK support that has been shown at Google I/O isn't inside it yet. It should be out soon though.

Regarding your missing std::function: did you include `<functional>` ?
Also, the std option should be defined as `-std`, not `--std`

Comment: Yeah made sure that <functional> was included. Turned out that the problem was fixed by changing the stl lib to **stl "c++_shared"**.

On another note the includes system in preview 3 is still pretty bad, had to manually add every single includes path to the gradle config just to get it to notice everything and now am running into a problem where it tries to compile web and ios files as well since the project is cross platform and contains all the implementation files inside the main project src folder.

Seems like there is still a way to go before full NDK support, just tired of Eclipse NDK.

Comment: Given what you say about the include files, I may have to wait until full release, but when you said 'adding stl "stlport_static" cFlags "-O2 --std=c++11 " to Gradle Config, where did you do that?

Comment: You can do that under `android { defaultConfig { ndk { ... } } }`